# How to disable lazyload in subsonic programmatically?

Tags: subsonic, lazy-loading

By default if the table has FK, subsonic also retrieves data of the FK table.
Is it possible to disable this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, as it stands the answer is simply yes. But I don't think that's going to be too helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask for rows of data from a particular table, SubSonic will only give you the rows from that table, even if it has foreign keys out to other tables.  e.g.

```
EmployeeCollection employees = new EmployeeCollection().Load();
```

If you want the data from a related table (via a foreign key), you would have to follow the references to the other tables, incurring the trip to the database.  e.g.

```
foreach(Employee e in employees){
  Debug.Print(e.Department.DepartmentName);
}
```

where Department is the related foreign key table and DepartmentName is a column in that table.